# How to force Facebook aggregate similar posted stories in one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Im using Koala and GraphApi ti post to Facebook from my app in case user listen some song at my website. So if user listened few songs in the row I expect Facebook will aggregate it in one wall post but instead it creates new post each time. Can I force Facebook somehow to aggregate it ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, you will have to make yourself the logic that once in a while you post to Facebook a aggregated version. There is no way to send in individual data and force Facebook aggregate it.